# Submit timestamp to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add a timestamp to my database when I update a form, and for reason that I do not know, I am getting an error... and when just trying to insert the year, month, day I get "1988" inserted into my database. I use a similar timestamp elsewhere on the same site and it works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Note: yes I know I should be using mysqli and I'm vulnerable to sql injection. I plan on converting the entire site later in the year.

```
    $homeScore = ((strlen($game['homeScore']) > 0) ? $game['homeScore'] : 'NULL');
    $homeOdds = (str_replace("\xBD", ".5", $homeScore));
    $visitorScore = ((strlen($game['visitorScore']) > 0) ? $game['visitorScore'] : 'NULL');
    $visitorOdds = (str_replace("\xBD", ".5", $visitorScore));

    $odds_timestamp = date("Y-m-d g:i:s A");

    $sql = "update " . $db_prefix . "schedule ";
    $sql .= " set odds_timestamp = " . $odds_timestamp . ", homeOdds = " . $homeOdds . ", visitorOdds = " . $visitorOdds . "";
    $sql .= " where gameID = " . $game['gameID'];
    mysql_query($sql) or die('Error updating odds: ' . mysql_error());
```

Comment: what about the column itself, is it DATETIME?

Comment: It was `DATETIME` and that didn't work, so I changed it to `VARCHAR`, same error either way

Comment: `echo $odds_timestamp = date("Y-m-d g:i:s A");` what does that show? it's a string ;-)

Comment: You would be best advised to make the datatype a DATETIME or TIMESTAMP as if you keep the VARCHAR it will make the data much more difficult to process later. Just change the `date()` to produce a legal MYSQL data format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without error message, Its difficult to say something.
or if you can print your query it will be helpful.

but try with.

```
odds_timestamp = '" . $odds_timestamp . "'
```

to make it explicit string.

Comment: You are right, and this keeps my AM/PM. Thank you so much.

Comment: You would be best advised to make the datatype a DATETIME or TIMESTAMP as if you keep the VARCHAR it will make the data much more difficult to process later. Just change the date() to produce a legal MYSQL data format. You can always add the AM/PM when you present the date time to any user. VARCHAR date/time will really mess with your selection criteria later as well. Remember - Database for DATA, Browser for PRESENTATION

Answer (score 3):

You have missing (single) quotes `" . $odds_timestamp . "`

that will need to be `'" . $odds_timestamp . "'` since it will contain characters that MySQL will complain about... being hyphens.

- That is a string.

Now, if any of your other variables are also strings, they too need to be quoted as shown.

I.e.: `'" . $string . "'` as opposed to `" . $integer . "`

More on string literals:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html

Pay attention to Riggs' comments, one of which being:

*"You would be best advised to make the datatype a DATETIME or TIMESTAMP as if you keep the VARCHAR it will make the data much more difficult to process later. Just change the date() to produce a legal MYSQL data format"*

Using a VARCHAR won't fix it, as it still considered as a string literal for the column.

New comments by Riggs:

*"You would be best advised to make the datatype a DATETIME or TIMESTAMP as if you keep the VARCHAR it will make the data much more difficult to process later. Just change the date() to produce a legal MYSQL data format. You can always add the AM/PM when you present the date time to any user. VARCHAR date/time will really mess with your selection criteria later as well. Remember - Database for DATA, Browser for PRESENTATION"*

Comment: Especially as it is now a VARCHAR

Comment: @RiggsFolly that too Smokey

Comment: Of course the Data Type of this column looks like it may be a movable feast

Answer (score 1):

You can use MySQL's NOW() function, which returns current datetime.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a timestamp column in the database table with an on update set current timestamp clause.

Heres a simple example from [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html):

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Should take care of it and cut out the middle man. Win-win.